# WPF MVVM Multiple ContentControls in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want my `tabitem` to display multiple `usercontrols` in a grid fashion. Imagine having a `grid` in a single `tabitem` where the first row and the second row contains corresponding `usercontrol1` and `usercontrol2`. ViewModels for these user controls are `View1Model.cs` and `View2Model.cs`.

I can currently display a single `usercontrol` using the following method:

Code for `View.xaml`:

```
<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ItemTemplate>
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Code for `ViewModel.cs`:

```
public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs { get; set; }

public ToolViewModel ()
{
    Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
    Tabs.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Header", Content = new View1Model()});
}
```

Code for `TabItem.cs` (model):

```
public string Header { get; set; }
public ViewModelBase Content { get; set; }
```

Obviously, I can't add another one `ContentControl` to the same `Header` in this way. To solve the problem, I suppose I should firstly change `public ViewModelBase Content { get; set; }` to `public ViewModelBase[] Content { get; set; }`. However, I am not sure how I should display a list of ContentControl in xaml.

EDIT: I ended up using `ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>` instead of simple arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To solve the problem, I suppose I should firstly change `public ViewModelBase Content { get; set; }` to `public ViewModelBase[] Content { get; set; }`. However, I am not sure how I should display a list of `ContentControl` in xaml.

Use an `ItemsControl`:

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Content}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: It only displays .toString method of TabItem. I have the `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:View1Model}"> <views:View1/></DataTemplate>` set up, any ideas why?

Comment: Try to remove the `ContentControl`. You shouldn't need it since you have set up implicit data templates for your `ViewModelBase` types. See my edit.