# WPF ItemsControl and bugged DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Basically I'm having two related problems:

1) The same problem as in this question [How do I make an ItemsControl stretch to fill all availible space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653047/how-do-i-make-an-itemscontrol-stretch-to-fill-all-availible-space), basically the `ItemsControl` doesn't fill in the whole space and the provided solution with `DockedPanel` doesn't work for me, because I need the items to stack vertically and not horizontally. Is there any other way to achieve this than using complex dynamic Grids?

2) There seems to be something off with the way `DataGrid` is presented when I'm using the method in this question [WPF MVVM Multiple ContentControls in TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302519/wpf-mvvm-multiple-contentcontrols-in-tabcontrol).

[image]

The headers are for some reason crushed to the side, also adding info to the table makes it look very bad. This wouldn't normally happen if I wasn't using this method of `ItemsControl` to display the table.

Code for TabControl:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Content}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Code for `DataGrid` that is in the `UserControl` (`view.xaml`) which is bound to the above `TabControl`:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Margin="10 10 10 0" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                //...
                //Same for other columns
                //...
</DataGrid>
```

Removing Header style does not help.

Comment: What if you remove the `ScrollViewer` element from your `ContentTemplate`? The `DataGrid` has its own `ScrollViewer` element.

Comment: @mm8 yeah it worked, kinda strange, though I will need to now figure out how to add scrollviewer to other elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `ScrollViewer` element from your `ContentTemplate`. The `DataGrid` has its own `ScrollViewer` element built-in into its default `ControlTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer and the accepted answer is correct (there's a workaround):

[WPF ScrollViewer around DataGrid affects column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875765/wpf-scrollviewer-around-datagrid-affects-column-width)

As for my first question, I just sticked to `UniformGrid` and binded its row count to the ViewModel.